# Copy and Paste data into next empty row

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, optimization, google-sheets

I have a system generated spreadsheet that enters blank cells when there is more than one item inside an order number. For example, if Order 1 had three items, I would have three rows completely filled but only one with date. The header is like this:

```
Order Number | User | Date | Item
```

I Attached an example image from a sample dataset:

[image: Dataset image]

I tried the following code which does the job greatly but I couldn't finish the task because the execution is timing out every time the script is run (it stops around row number 1,000). My spreadsheet has about 3,000 rows and growing slowly. I read some instructions about trying to make the code more efficient but for me it is already very efficient (at least comparing it to VBA).
Any assistance is appreciated!

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();// get last row number
 
  for (i = 2; i < last; i++) { 
    var info = sheet.getRange(i, 3);
    Logger.log(info);
 
    if (info.isBlank()) {
      var data = sheet.getRange(i-1, 3).getValues(); //copy value from cell above with date
      sheet.getRange(i, 3).setValues(data); //paste value on empty cell
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is that `getValues` and `setValues` are used in the loop. By this, the process cost will be high. This has already been mentioned by [Rubén's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944703/7108653). So in order to reduce the cost, in your situation, how about the modification with the following flow?

1. Retrieve values from the column "C" using `getValues`.
2. Create an array for putting values to Spreadsheet.
3. Put the created array to the Spreadsheet using `setValues`.

When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();// get last row number

  // I modified below script.
  var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C" + last);

  // 1. Retrieve values from the column "C".
  var values = range.getValues();

  // 2. Create an array for putting values to Spreadsheet.
  var temp = "";
  var v = values.map(([c]) => [c.toString() != "" ? temp = c : temp]);

  // 3. Put the created array to the Spreadsheet.
  range.setValues(v);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It worked perfectly! And thanks for the reference material.

Comment: @Haddocks Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getRange` and other similar Spreadsheet Services (`Class SpreadsheetApp`) are "very" slow.

Instead of reading one range at each `for` iteration read the whole data range at once by using `getDataRange()` then `getValues()` then iterate over the Array that has all the data range values.

Related

- [Long processing time likely due to getValue and cell inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35289183/1595451)
- [Slow Archiving Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61642717/1595451)

Comment: I thought that when a sample modified script for OP's situation is proposed, it might help to understand about the modification points. So I proposed it as one of several modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your comment  @Tanaike. I'm hesitant to do that when there are already a lot of similar questions and the OP didn't  included a brief description of their search/research efforts. Anyway, I'm glad that you posted an answer  :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can understand about it. I thought that when the user can get the direction for resolving the user's issue, it might lead to the education as the user. So I proposed about it. But of course, when I could find the the clear duplicated question for resolving the issue, I would like to propose to refer it.

Comment: Ruben, thank you for the material. I am going to read the articles you posted. Actually I am new to javascript and Google Sheets (usually do a bit of Python or VBA for small tasks) and I wasn't aware of the slow process behind `getRange` and other SpreadSheet Services. I tried to search for similar questions but found myself reading about making the code efficient which is a big step to a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var shsr=2;//data start row
  var vs=sh.getRange(shsr,3,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){if(!r[0]){vs[i][0]=vs[i-1][0];}});
  sh.getRange(shsr,3,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: This also worked. Thank you Cooper for the solution!